# How to count tokens in word which don't duplicate java

Tags: regex, string, stringtokenizer

I want to count tokens in word which don't duplicate .

```
Example:
aabbcc
abc

Result:
0
3
```

I must use StrTokazizer or sth like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java,the following should work:

```
public class UniqueTokenCounter{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Arraylist<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

    int uniqueCount=0;

    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer("a b c b d");

    while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    {
       tokens.add(stringTokenizer.nextToken())
    }

    boolean unique=true;
    for(String uniqueToken : tokens) 
    {
       for(String token : tokens) 
       {
          if(uniqueToken.equals(token))
            unique=false;
       }
       if(unique)
          uniqueCount++;
       else
          unique=true;
    }
    //print uniqueCount
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
public int getUniqueTokensCount(String input)
{
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
    Set<Character> dups = new HashSet<Character>();

    for (char c: input.toCharArray())
        if (!set.add(c))
            dups.add(c);

    set.removeAll(dups);
    return set.size();
}
```

We collect all characters from the string in `set` and, if it is a duplicate, add the character to `dups`. When all the string has been parsed, we remove from `set` (which contains all individual characters) all found duplicates. The number of unique tokens is then this set's size.

This relies on the fact that a `Set`'s `.add()` operation will return `false` if the element to add is already present.